# Casting (int?)null vs. new int?() - Which is better?

Tags: c#, performance, nullable

I use `Nullable<T>` types quite a lot when loading values into classes and structs when I need them to be nullable, such as loading a nullable value from a database (as the example below).

Consider this snippet of code:

```
public class InfoObject
{
    public int? UserID { get; set; }
}

// Load the ID into an SqlInt32
SqlInt32 userID = reader.GetSqlInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("intUserID"));
```

When I need to load a value into a nullable property, sometimes I do this:

```
infoObject.UserID = userID.IsNull ? (int?)null : userID.Value;
```

Sometimes I do this instead:

```
infoObject.UserID = userID.IsNull ? new int?() : userID.Value;
```

Although they achieve the same result, I'd like to see if anyone knows which is better to use between `(int?)null` and `new int?()` with regards to performance, smallest IL code, best practices etc.?

Generally I've been favouring the `new int?()` version of the code above, but I'm not sure whether casting `(int?)null` is quicker for the compiler to resolve than `new int?()`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They will generate the same IL. Use whichever you find easier to read.

When you talk about something being "quicker for the compiler to resolve" are you talking about micro-optimising your *build* times? I have no idea which would be faster there, but I doubt it will make a reliably-measurable difference for any significant body of code.

Personally I use `null` whenever I can do so with no ambiguity; I think I still generally prefer the cast to calling `new`, but it makes no real difference.

Comment: I agree with you. `(int?)null` looks far better than `new int?()` especially when used within in-line conditional statements like my example shows.  Regarding your question: you answered it when you said the IL is the same. Build times aren't currently an issue (unless I use TFSBuild, but that's a whole different story) so so-long as the IL matches, I'm happy :)

Comment: My favorite (with the cast version as a very close second) is `default(int?)`.